# insert into data as RDF in ARC2

Tags: php, semantic-web

I'm working on a semantic web application with php and ARC2. I couldn't find any good tutorial with practical examples.What I want to do is save some articles as RDF document in database with ARC and then run SPARQL on them. I've read the ARC documentation but I can not find good and practical examples, specially for insert.Could any one help me???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sample from my master's project:

```
if($variableName){

prefix PREFIX: <http://yourprefix.owl#>
INSERT INTO <http://localhost/yourontologyfilename.owl>{
 <http://yourprefix.owl#some-identifier> rdf:Type PREFIX:Category;
         PREFIX:Title $variableName; 
}
```

It worked fine for me, this should do the trick!
Of course you have to add sanity and security checks :-)

In my case, protege' you'd run the query this way:

```
prefix SEMKNOW: <http://sk.owl#>
INSERT INTO <http://localhost/SEMKNOW.owl>{
 <http://sk.owl#C-21> rdf:Type SEMKNOW:ConferencePapers;
         SEMKNOW:Title "A semantic knowledge management system for scholarly repositories"; 
}
```

You should read the sparql 1.1 and 1.0 official docs and use protege to test your queries, it definitely speeds up your dev process. Also check out  [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160720072101/http://answers.semanticweb.com:80/questions/16454/help-with-insert-query-arc2) the [site](http://answers.semanticweb.com/) in general is more specific to your line, so checking it out wouldn't hurt.